# Get visibility of Lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard

How can I check from a Service if the KeyGuard (Lockscreen) is visible? I want to support the original and custom Lockscreens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen locks only when the device turns the screen off.

You should extend `BroadcastReceiver` and implement `onReceive`, like this:

```
public class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            //screen has been switched off!
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to register it and you'll start receiving events when the screen is switched off:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
appBroadcastReceiver = new AppBroadcastReceiver(yourActivity);
registerReceiver(appBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

There is an edge case where users have their device set to lock `n` seconds after the screen goes off, you might want to add a check in your broadcast receiver for the `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and check the time between them.

Comment: okay that's great so far but I need an Event if the user switch from the lockscreen to the homescreen - sry the question was inaccurate...

Comment: Listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` in that case